# UIAccelerationValue angle

Tags: iphone

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration

Using the above method we got an acceleration value of (x and y and z).Now i want to find angle between (x and y) and (y and z) and (z and x).How can i do this?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: The angles between x and y, y and z, z and x are all 90 degrees. Do you mean the angle between the acceleration vector (what you call acceleration value) and the x, y & z axes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your acceleration vector is a = (x, y, z), then the angles between this vector and the three axes are given by:

> cos (angleXaxis) = x / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
>
> cos (angleYaxis) = y / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
>
> cos (angleZaxis) = z / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)

To get the angles themselves you'll need to use the inverse cos function

Comment: Sorry for the late replay pheelicks.. I want to show angles when the ipod is over the air.

Comment: I want to show angles like in the  Advanced Bubble Level Free application